# Pandas Error Handling - "day is out of range for month"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wonder how do I handle and spot the data which has wrong format in pandas.

I tried to convert string into pd data form however,
somewhere in the middle the format is not in line with the format that was expected (I assume), an error message popped.

1. I want to print what the data is
2. and I want to fix it into the right format that I could keep moving on
3. how do I handle this issue?

My code is as below.

```
def date_format(df):
    
    target = pd.to_datetime(df['Issue Date'])
    
    return target
```

The error message is

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py
> in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors,
> require_iso8601, allow_object)    2053         try:
> -> 2054             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)    2055             # If
> tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()
>
> TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 seg0=generateDb(csv,2017,1000000,0)
>
> in generateDb(csv, year, segment,
> index)
> 2
> 3     targetSeg0=segment_df(csv,segment,index)
> ----> 4     targetSeg0['Issue Date']=date_format(targetSeg0)
> 5     targetSeg0=remove_etc(targetSeg0)
> 6     filter_date(targetSeg0,year)
>
> in date_format(df)
> 1 def date_format(df):
> ----> 2     target = pd.to_datetime(df['Issue Date'])
> 3     return target
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py
> in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact,
> unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
> 797                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
> 798     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
> --> 799         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
> 800         if not cache_array.empty:
> 801             result = arg.map(cache_array)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py
> in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
> 168         unique_dates = unique(arg)
> 169         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
> --> 170             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
> 171             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
> 172     return cache_array
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py
> in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors,
> infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
> 457         assert format is None or infer_datetime_format
> 458         utc = tz == "utc"
> --> 459         result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
> 460             arg,
> 461             dayfirst=dayfirst,
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py
> in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors,
> require_iso8601, allow_object)    2057             return
> values.view("i8"), tz_parsed    2058         except (ValueError,
> TypeError):
> -> 2059             raise e    2060     2061     if tz_parsed is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py
> in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors,
> require_iso8601, allow_object)    2042     2043     try:
> -> 2044         result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(    2045             data,    2046             errors=errors,
>
> pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing._parse_delimited_date()
>
> datetime.pxd in cpython.datetime.datetime_new()
>
> ValueError: day is out of range for month

I'm eventually gonna filter the data as below.

```
def filter_date(df,year):
    booldf =  df['Issue Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-01-01")
    booldf2 = df['Issue Date'] <= pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-12-31")
    return df[
        (df['Issue Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-01-01")) & (df['Issue Date'] <= pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-12-31"))
    ]
```

Sample data form is as below.

[image]

The Error occurs because of wrong data like below. (51th month doesn't exist).. I guess this is where the error came from.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data in code form (i.e. `pd.DataFrame({'Issue Date': [...]})`

Comment: @rudolfovic Thank you! I just added sample data form

Comment: Using: df = pd.DataFrame(["09/26/2016", "06/14/2017", "09/05/2018", "06/16/2017", "05/09/2018"], columns=['date'])    it works fine: pd.to_datetime(df.date) outputs a dataframe with the dates as datetime64 column. Please provide an example where it does not work (with the exact code to reproduce it). Thank you

Comment: @n4321d Where the error happened is where the data format is having abnormal data form. Can I exclude the false data when I sort out dataframe? For example,  when I do this, target = pd.to_datetime(df['Issue Date']) "if some string doesn't seem right, exclude it and return a data frame."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I assume this will help:

Using as example (99/99/9999 is the incorrect data):

`df = pd.DataFrame(["09/26/2016", "06/14/2017", "09/05/2018", "06/16/2017", "05/09/2018", "99/99/9999"], columns=['Issue Date'])`.

You mean something like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Issue Date"], errors="coerce")
```

output:
[image]

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

if you want to you drop the rows with NaTs next with:

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Issue Date'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems like exactly what I was wondering.

Comment: welcome. Be careful that the dropna will also drop rows with other NaNs, you can use subset to define to only use the Issue date column. I edited my answer